# Basic ARIA landmark roles are not recognized by screen readers

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm researching the implementation of ARIA with **HTML5** and have built a tech demo on my **localhost** to manage scope before exporting to a production website.

I tested using **IE11/Firefox 23** and **Jaws 15/Fangs** - Firefox Add-in, after adding landmark roles to **HTML5** tags.

None of the above mentioned browser/screen reader combinations recognize ARIA roles or landmarks (i.e. no change in how the page was announced before/after role attributes were added to existing tags).

The code I am testing with:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
   <head>
       <title>ARIA Test</title>
   </head>
   <body role="document">
       <div role="banner"> Hello world!</div>
       <div role="main">Greetings Earth!</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have any recommendation for triggering ARIA roles in screen readers?

Comment: ARIA landmark roles are primarily navigation mechanisms that are listed and traversed through shortcut keys (semicolon and shift+semicolon in JAWS), so screen readers may not announce them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First - remove role of [document](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#document), that is essentially the default for HTML docs, so only needed when you've used a role of application.

Secondly, I would test with a more common set of user-agents, e.g. NVDA with Firefox or Jaws with IE.

The most common screen readers (by usage) have supported landmarks for quite a while.

From an article in 2011, [HTML5 Accessibility Chops: ARIA landmark support](http://blog.paciellogroup.com/2011/07/html5-accessibility-chops-aria-landmark-support/):

> - NVDA and JAWS when using Internet Explorer 9 or Firefox 3+.
> - VoiceOver when using Safari on iOS 4+
> - Orca (Linux screen reader) using Firefox 3+ supports landmarks (not tested).

The article also shows the keyboard shortcuts to test for support.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll use the note about different UA strings & screen readers to expand my testing. Unfortunately, the keyboard shortcuts don't work as claimed in the article, but I feel good that they what I've coded is designed to the spec (aside from the semantic use of document). It's difficult to separate issues with my code and compat problems with the third-party software (JAWS, etc.) when learning something new.

Comment: If you'd like to get deep into how JAWs deals with things, try their ARIA doc: http://www.freedomscientific.com/PDF/visionloss/manuals/DevDoc/JAWS-ARIA-Support.doc